# Lucene 3.4 overwriting the document in index

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to add a document to the index, but when I try to run the following function, it returns `numDocs` as `1` and overwrites the document on the previous one! Am I doing something wrong? I did the same on another project and it worked fine!

```
    IndexWriter writer;
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File("/home/omid/Desktop/Indexes"));
    writer = new IndexWriter(dir, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new NumericField("id", Field.Store.YES, false).setIntValue(writer.numDocs()));
    doc.add(new NumericField("day", Field.Store.YES, false).setIntValue(13));
    doc.add(new NumericField("month", Field.Store.YES, false).setIntValue(1));
    doc.add(new NumericField("year", Field.Store.YES, false).setIntValue(1387));
    doc.add(new Field("content", new FileReader(new File(filename)), Field.TermVector.YES));
    doc.add(new Field("address", filename,Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    writer.close();
    mes = "Indexed Filename: " + filename;
    mes = mes + "<BR>Number of docs: " + writer.numDocs();
```

Is there anything changed from lucene 3.0 in 3.4 or I am doing it wr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`IndexWriter` constructor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#IndexWriter%28org.apache.lucene.store.Directory,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer,%20boolean,%20org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength%29)'s third argument specifies whether the index should be created or not.  If `create=true`, as in your example, any old index is deleted and replaced with the new one.  If it's false, it will append to an existing index.

Also, this style of `IndexWriter` constructor is deprecated in 3.4, and absent in 4.x.  It would be much better to pass an [`IndexWriterConfig`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.html) into the `IndexWriter`, instead.